# The value of input type text I get from localStorage is not submitted

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I am building a react app that has a form. The app should remember the user's input and prefill them the next time they access the page, with an option to edit the values. I use local storage for this and an example of my input field is:

```
                        <div className="input-field mb-40">
                            <input 
                            placeholder='First Name...'
                            type="text" 
                            id='first_name'
                            value={ localStorage.getItem('first_name') || "" }
                            required 
                            className='validate f-inpt'
                            onChange={this.handleChange}
                            />
    
                            <label htmlFor="first_name" className="active fnt-16">
                                First Name
                            </label>
                        </div>
```

My onChange method is:

```
    handleChange = (e) => {
    localStorage.setItem([e.target.id], e.target.value)
    this.setState({
        [e.target.id]: e.target.value
    })
}
```

On Chrome and Edge, it works well but on Safari, the values show on the form but are not submitted when the form is submitted. When I update the state with the form and log to console, I get an Object that contains an Array. The array contains these values.

Is there anything that I am doing wrong? Please Help!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your using Class-based components you can use `componentDidMount()` to check if the key from `localStorage` are existing. If you're using react Hooks then you can use `useEffect()` and apply same logic when checking the values.

But, seeing from your code, I assume you are using class-based component. Hence, `componentDidMount()` can be the solution.

Inside the `componentDidMount()`, you can assign the values to your state and call them in your form.

Read the docs here https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning, your localStorage has information, but your state is empty.

Try this:

```
componentDidMount() {
   const item = localStorage.getItem("first_name");
    if (item) {
      this.setState({first_name: item})
    }
}
```